# Can't upload image using Paperclip 4.0 Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, imagemagick, paperclip

I've installed ImageMagick and I've installed the gem Paperclip (version 4.0). I've added:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16'
```

to the development.rb

My photo.rb Model has this:

```
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg']
```

I can choose a file in photos/new.html.erb but once I click on 'Create photo' button, the page reloads with a Paperclip specific error message saying:

```
1 error prohibited this photo from being saved:
Image translation missing: 
en.activerecord.errors.models.photo.attributes.image.spoofed_media_type
```

Can someone help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That message is raised by a validation check for content spoofing.

For Paperclip v.4 this generates a bug https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429

While for Paperclip v.3, it seems it just throws a deprecation warning, https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1423

So I'd wait for Paperclip team to solve this bug before using version 4. At the moment I'd rather keep using version 3.

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.5.3"
```

Comment: Thanks - I switched to version 3.5.3 and it worked. I guess using the latest version isn't always a good thing!

Comment: @mgambella if you were using aws-sdk, which version did you installed?

Answer (score 10):

Add this to an initializer to disable spoofing protection:

```
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on `Paperclip v3.5.1` (hopefully will still work in `V4`):

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
        styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? { *** image_styles ***}  : { *** video_styles ***},
        processors: lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }

def is_video?
    attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
end

def is_image?
    attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
end
```