# Error when upload images/documents via Paperclip: "has an extension that does not match its contents"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I ran into the error that when I upload images to S3 via Paperclip, I get an error: `has an extension that does not match its contents`. On a local machine, I do not experience such problems, only for production. This was observed after the update of rails `4.1.1 -> 4.1.16` and ruby `2.1.5 -> 2.3.1` and changing the instance to AWS.

Here is my validation:

```
validates_attachment    :document,
                        content_type: { not: "application/x-msdownload" }
```

I do not understand what the problem is. Any file I upload, whether it's an image or a document (any extension) gets this error. Tell me please, with what it can be connected?

**UPD**

I found in log this:

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename example1.png (["image/png"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

**UPD 2**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912537/5923919) solved my problem

Comment: Not sure what version of `paperclip` you are using but you should check since: `Paperclip now requires Ruby version >= 2.1 and Rails version >= 4.2 (only if you're going to use Paperclip with Ruby on Rails.)` (from https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#requirements)

Comment: @jdgray I use version 4.2. This bug related with spoof.

Comment: Oh okay your question said `4.1.1 -> 4.1.16`

Comment: @jdgray sorry, my rails version `4.1.6` Paperclip version `4.2`. I think that you meant paperclip version.

Comment: Your question specifically says: "update of rails 4.1.1 -> 4.1.16"....