# Paperclip spoofing error on new Rails install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I have set up Rails on a new computer and forked my repository from github. This repository works perfectly fine on my desktop computer.

But now when uploading a profile pic for my User model I get this error

```
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Maxence/AppData/Local/Temp/8ab130f329c41e18078e316bdd9fc5ae20170705-7476-1788hla.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 24112014-DSC00522.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Maxence/AppData/Local/Temp/8ab130f329c41e18078e316bdd9fc5ae20170705-7476-g6nde9.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 24112014-DSC00522.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I am not sure where the problem comes from

- I have made sure I downloaded 32 bits devkit (matching my Ruby version 2.3.3 32 bits)
- I have this environment path : C:\DevKit32bits\mingw\bin
- I also have system path : C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16 and C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32
- I have matched Rails gem with Desktop computer (I had Rails 5.1.2 and 5.1.1 on old desktop computer)

Only thing, when i run `which convert` on the new install, I get `C:\Windows\system32\convert.EXE` as answer from command, whereas I got an error on desktop computer and still Paperclip was working fine...

adding `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Windows\system32\'` generate new errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912537/126636

Comment: Looks like you are finding the Windows convert.exe and not the ImageMagick convert.exe. Many people rename ImageMagick 6 convert to something else. Also in ImageMagick 7, "convert" is replaced with "magick" in the command line processing. So a search for convert.exe will not find ImageMagick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Paperclip Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912322/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-error)

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 that may be the problem: I am using Imagemagick 7 on new install and 6.9 on old install. But Paperclip main page mentions typing `which convert` not `which magick`, they don't really make a difference between Imagemagick versions. And my system path are here too... Does paperclip knows it has to call `magick` instead of `convert` for I guess is image styling ? That's a bit weird... I will install Imagemagick 6.9 from the other computer and see what happens. thanks for pointing this

Comment: I know little about paperclip. Perhaps they have not upgrade their docs for IM 7.